# Multiplying different data fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to multiply two different sets of info (in different columns and cells) and have the answer end up in another column/cell in the same feature. But not only multiply those values for data references, but to become a functional formula so that if the two sets of values change, the answer will change automatically? And if this is possible, can it be shared to arcgis online.

[image]

I would like to multiply acres and manure application rate and it be answered in the Total Manure Column, like in the row "Adams Farm". I know how to calculate it after the data is entered. But I would like it to be automatically answered if the either acres or manure application rate changes.

I would also like this to be uploaded to arcgis online and used with the collector app. Is this possible?

Comment: If your data source is an Excel spreadsheet then you can multiply the columns to make another value and when entered, in Excel, the sheet should auto calculate. Cells with formulas *should* appear in ArcGIS as their calculated value. To do this in ArcGIS would take a small amount of code in ArcObjects using IEditEvents.OnChangeFeature http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000p2000000 and OnCreateFeature http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnCreateFeature_Event/0020000000p6000000/ maybe.

Comment: Are you set on using Collector? Survey123 allows you to have calculations take place as you enter information. It just lacks some of the nice things Collector has (like a functional map interface). Having a field update on the entry of data is not possible with the regular attribute table in Arc. That being said, you could write a script / Add-in to do this for you, however it would take two syncs from Collector to get it to appear. One sync for the update to the server, the script would run, then a second sync to send the data back to Collector.